# MODx not display correct image path

Tags: url, cms, images, content-management, wysiwyg

In the MODx WYSIWYG whenever I click the Image icon to insert an image, followed by browse image it generates the wrong path: /data/12/1/111/99/1111262/user/1169144/htdocs/images/image.jpg instead of assets/images/image.jpg

I have checked my Resource URL and Resource Path and they both look correct. Has anyone ever experienced MODx rewriting your paths to the server vs what it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people look to `Tools > Configuration > Interface & Features` for the `Resource Path` and `Resource URL`, however, it is also directly related to the Web User logged in as.

If you go to `Security > Manage Users` Select your username and go to `User` You will notice there are the same `Resource Path` and `Resource URL` These need to be correct as well.